# Prevent browser to launch intent chooser for a redirect in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

I have an Url that I want to be handled by browser.

In my app I've defined and `intent-filter` for all Urls within my domain.

When Url has a redirect to other part of my domain a chooser is shown.

I would like to prevent such behavior and handle all redirects inside browser.